# Unable to display words by dask.visualize()

Tags: python, dask, graphviz

I'm trying to use dask.visualize() to display the parallelism structure. However, I can only get squares representing words.

The codes:

```py
@dask.delayed
def inc(x):
    sleep(1)
    return x + 1

@dask.delayed
def add(x, y):
    sleep(1)
    return x + y

x = inc(1)
y = inc(2)
z = add(x, y)

z.visualize()
```

The output:

[image]

The system is Linux on cluster. I used `conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz` as recommended to install the dependencies of graphviz. I've searched for some discussions. It might relate to the font dependencies? But I thought installing python-graphviz should deal with those dependencies already...

Below are the packages I installed (by conda):

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main
aiohttp                   3.6.2            py37h7b6447c_0
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py37h7b6447c_1
async-timeout             3.0.1                    py37_0
attrs                     20.1.0                     py_0
backcall                  0.2.0                      py_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    3.1.5                      py_0
bokeh                     2.2.1                    py37_0
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py37h7b6447c_1000
ca-certificates           2020.6.20            hecda079_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.16.0            h18b612c_1001    conda-forge
certifi                   2020.6.20        py37hc8dfbb8_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.2           py37he30daa8_0
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003
click                     7.1.2                      py_0
cloudpickle               1.6.0                      py_0
conda                     4.8.4            py37hc8dfbb8_2    conda-forge
conda-package-handling    1.6.1            py37h7b6447c_0
cryptography              3.1              py37h1ba5d50_0
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0
cytoolz                   0.10.1           py37h7b6447c_0
dask                      2.25.0                     py_0    conda-forge
dask-core                 2.25.0                     py_0
dask-jobqueue             0.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
dask-labextension         3.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
dask-mpi                  2.21.0           py37h61907ee_0    conda-forge
dask_labextension         3.0.0                         0    conda-forge
dbus                      1.13.16              hb2f20db_0
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0
distributed               2.25.0                   py37_0
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0
expat                     2.2.9                he6710b0_2
fontconfig                2.13.1            he4413a7_1000    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.2               h5ab3b9f_0
fribidi                   1.0.10               h516909a_0    conda-forge
fsspec                    0.8.0                      py_0
gettext                   0.19.8.1             h5e8e0c9_1    conda-forge
glib                      2.65.0               h3eb4bd4_0
graphite2                 1.3.13            he1b5a44_1001    conda-forge
graphviz                  2.42.3               h0511662_0    conda-forge
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1
gstreamer                 1.14.0               hb31296c_0
harfbuzz                  2.4.0                hca77d97_0
hdbscan                   0.8.26           py37h03ebfcd_1    conda-forge
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0
icu                       58.2                 he6710b0_3
idna                      2.10                       py_0
importlib-metadata        1.7.0                    py37_0
importlib_metadata        1.7.0                         0
intel-openmp              2020.2                      254
ipykernel                 5.3.4            py37h5ca1d4c_0
ipython                   7.18.1           py37h5ca1d4c_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.17.2                   py37_0
jinja2                    2.11.2                     py_0
joblib                    0.16.0                     py_0
jpeg                      9d                   h516909a_0    conda-forge
json5                     0.9.5                      py_0
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py37_1
jupyter-server-proxy      1.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.6                      py_0
jupyter_core              4.6.3                    py37_0
jupyterlab                2.2.6                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         1.2.0                      py_0
kiwisolver                1.2.0            py37hfd86e86_0
lcms2                     2.11                 h396b838_0
ld_impl_linux-64          2.33.1               h53a641e_7
libedit                   3.1.20191231         h14c3975_1
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0
libsodium                 1.0.18               h7b6447c_0
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0
libtiff                   4.1.0                h2733197_1
libtool                   2.4.6             h516909a_1005    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.32.1            h14c3975_1000    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.14                 h7b6447c_0
libxml2                   2.9.10               he19cac6_1
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1
lz4-c                     1.9.2                he6710b0_1
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h14c3975_1
matplotlib                3.3.1                         0
matplotlib-base           3.3.1            py37h817c723_0
mistune                   0.8.4           py37h14c3975_1001
mkl                       2020.2                      256
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37he904b0f_0
mkl_fft                   1.1.0            py37h23d657b_0
mkl_random                1.1.1            py37h0573a6f_0
mpi                       1.0                       mpich
mpi4py                    3.0.3            py37hf046da1_1
mpich                     3.3.2                hc856adb_0
msgpack-python            1.0.0            py37hfd86e86_1
multidict                 4.7.3            py37h7b6447c_0
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_1
nbformat                  5.0.7                      py_0
ncurses                   6.2                  he6710b0_1
nodejs                    10.13.0              he6710b0_0
notebook                  6.1.1                    py37_0
numpy                     1.19.1           py37hbc911f0_0
numpy-base                1.19.1           py37hfa32c7d_0
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0
openssl                   1.1.1g               h516909a_1    conda-forge
packaging                 20.4                       py_0
pandas                    1.1.1            py37he6710b0_0
pandoc                    2.10.1                        0
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1
pango                     1.42.4               h7062337_4    conda-forge
parso                     0.7.0                      py_0
partd                     1.1.0                      py_0
pcre                      8.44                 he6710b0_0
pexpect                   4.8.0                    py37_1
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py37_1001
pillow                    7.2.0            py37hb39fc2d_0
pip                       20.2.2                   py37_0
pixman                    0.38.0            h516909a_1003    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.8.0                      py_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.7                      py_0
psutil                    5.7.2            py37h7b6447c_0
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py37_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37h7b6447c_0
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2
pygments                  2.6.1                      py_0
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                     py_1
pyparsing                 2.4.7                      py_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h05f1152_2
pyrsistent                0.16.0           py37h7b6447c_0
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_1
python                    3.7.7                hcff3b4d_5
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0
python-graphviz           0.14.1             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.7                     1_cp37m    conda-forge
pytz                      2020.1                     py_0
pyyaml                    5.3.1            py37h7b6447c_1
pyzmq                     19.0.1           py37he6710b0_1
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1
readline                  8.0                  h7b6447c_0
requests                  2.24.0                     py_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py37h7b6447c_1
scikit-learn              0.23.2           py37h0573a6f_0
scipy                     1.5.2            py37h0b6359f_0
seaborn                   0.10.1                     py_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0
setuptools                49.6.0                   py37_0
simpervisor               0.3                        py_1    conda-forge
sip                       4.19.8           py37hf484d3e_0
six                       1.15.0                     py_0
sortedcontainers          2.2.2                      py_0
sqlite                    3.33.0               h62c20be_0
tblib                     1.7.0                      py_0
terminado                 0.8.3                    py37_0
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0
threadpoolctl             2.1.0              pyh5ca1d4c_0
tk                        8.6.10               hbc83047_0
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0
tornado                   6.0.4            py37h7b6447c_1
tqdm                      4.48.2                     py_0
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0
typing_extensions         3.7.4.3                    py_0
urllib3                   1.25.10                    py_0
wcwidth                   0.2.5                      py_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
wheel                     0.35.1                     py_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0
xorg-font-util            1.3.2                h516909a_0    conda-forge
xorg-kbproto              1.0.7             h14c3975_1002    conda-forge
xorg-libice               1.0.10               h516909a_0    conda-forge
xorg-libsm                1.2.3             h84519dc_1000    conda-forge
xorg-libx11               1.6.12               h516909a_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxext              1.3.4                h516909a_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxpm               3.5.13               h516909a_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxrender           0.9.10            h516909a_1002    conda-forge
xorg-libxt                1.1.5             h516909a_1003    conda-forge
xorg-renderproto          0.11.1            h14c3975_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xextproto            7.3.0             h14c3975_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xproto               7.0.31            h14c3975_1007    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h7b6447c_0
yaml                      0.2.5                h7b6447c_0
yarl                      1.5.1            py37h7b6447c_0
yarn                      0.25.2                        0
zeromq                    4.3.2                he6710b0_2
zict                      2.0.0                      py_0
zipp                      3.1.0                      py_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3
zstd                      1.4.5                h9ceee32_0
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I realize if I select the format as svg instead of the default png, it works. `z.visualize(format = 'svg')`

Comment: ^ You could include this as an answer, or at least a workaround. I don't know what fonts or packages you need installed on your system for graphviz to be able to generate proper PNG, sorry. Maybe this can be reported to graphviz.

Comment: @mdurant Thank you for the reply! I was thinking about the font also, but not sure to go deep because I didn't touch the default font setting. I'll try to check the font and report to graphviz.